# Fetching data in AsyncTask

Tags: android, azure, android-asynctask

I am trying to pull data from Microsoft Azure with this method. The problem is that it can sometimes be really slow, and I need these data in the shared preferences to do anything else in the application. How can I create a loading dialog that will wait for the data to be fetched? I tried putting this method in the AsyncTask doInBackground() method, but the dialog would just appear and then disappear after a millisecond. What is the right way to do this? I was reading similar topics on stackoverflow, but never found a solution.

Thank you!

```
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>  
    {  
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private MainActivity activity;

        public LoadViewTask(MainActivity activity) {

            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }
        private Context context;
        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute()  
        {  
            //Create a new progress dialog  
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading...",  
                    "", false, false);  
        }  

        //The code to be executed in a background thread.  
        @Override  
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)  
        {  

            try  
            {  

                    mClient.invokeApi("getsettings", jObj, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JsonElement result, Exception error,
                                ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SettingsPrefs", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            if (error != null) {
                                System.out.println("Error");
                            } else {
                                JsonObject res = result.getAsJsonObject();
                                try {


                                    if(res.get("gender").toString().equals("null")){
                                        userGender = res.get("gender").toString();
                                        editor.putString("gender", userGender);
                                    } else {
                                        int index1 = res.get("gender").toString().indexOf("\"");
                                        int index2 = res.get("gender").toString().lastIndexOf("\"");
                                        editor.putString("gender", res.get("gender").toString().substring(index1+1, index2));

                                    }
                                    if(res.get("dob").toString().equals("null")){
                                        userDob = res.get("dob").toString();
                                        editor.putString("dob", userDob);
                                    } else {
                                        editor.putString("dob", res.get("dob").toString().substring(1, 11));

                                    }
                                    if (res.get("club").isJsonNull()) {
                                        userClub = 0;
                                        editor.putInt("userClub", userClub);
                                        System.out.println("userclub is null in MA: "+userClub);
                                    } else {
                                        editor.putInt("userClub", res.get("club").getAsInt());


                                    }

                                    editor.commit();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });

            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            return null;
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)  
        {  
            //close the progress dialog  
            dialog.dismiss();
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any dialog in your code please post your complete code

Comment: I added the whole code now

Comment: what is this mClient.invokeApi ?

Comment: It's the API of Microsoft Azure. The way of calling a custom mobile service API.

Comment: Ok I think you no need to write asynctask because its is already uses thread.

Comment: So how would I do this? Display a loading dialog until all data is fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this steps

1) Create Method say loadDataFromServer() and put code inside

```
public void loadDataFromServer() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "", false, false);

        try {

            mClient.invokeApi("getsettings", jObj, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JsonElement result, Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SettingsPrefs", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    if (error != null) {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    } else {
                        JsonObject res = result.getAsJsonObject();
                        try {

                            if (res.get("gender").toString().equals("null")) {
                                userGender = res.get("gender").toString();
                                editor.putString("gender", userGender);
                            } else {
                                int index1 = res.get("gender").toString().indexOf("\"");
                                int index2 = res.get("gender").toString().lastIndexOf("\"");
                                editor.putString("gender", res.get("gender").toString().substring(index1 + 1, index2));

                            }
                            if (res.get("dob").toString().equals("null")) {
                                userDob = res.get("dob").toString();
                                editor.putString("dob", userDob);
                            } else {
                                editor.putString("dob", res.get("dob").toString().substring(1, 11));

                            }
                            if (res.get("club").isJsonNull()) {
                                userClub = 0;
                                editor.putInt("userClub", userClub);
                                System.out.println("userclub is null in MA: " + userClub);
                            } else {
                                editor.putInt("userClub", res.get("club").getAsInt());

                            }

                            editor.commit();

                            dialog.dismiss(); // / DISMISS DIALOG HERE
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

2) Call this method like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadDataFromServer();

    }
```

3) dismiss dialog inside onCompleted() method. (I have added that line). just copy the method and call it.

Comment: Yeah as soon as I wrote that comment I realized what you were thinking :) I am trying this now..

Comment: Wow it was such an easy solution and I would have never come up with it.. It works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ProgressDialog` and `show()` it before you call `mClient.invokeApi` and `dismiss()` it on `onCompleted` after you have done all the required processes

Answer (score 0):

Try setting indeterminate to true,

```
//Create a new progress dialog  
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Loading...",  
                    "", true, false);
```